# How to specialize scatter plots in r?

Tags: r

First of all when I tried to draw regression line, an error occured.

I have two datas to compare;

```
dismax<-list(1.14, 2.281, 2.825, 2.965) 
normax<-list(1.8, 2, 2.4, 2.6)
```

With the code below, I've plotted scatter diagram.

```
plot(normax, dismax, main="Minute Max.",
       xlab="Historical Values ", ylab="Disaggregated Values", pch=19)
```

Then I tried to draw regression line with this code;

```
abline(lm(normax~dismax), col="red")
```

And the error occured;

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = normax ~ dismax,
>   drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :    invalid type (list) for variable
>   'normax'

How can I solve this?

---

And second question;
As you will see X axis is ending with 2.6, and Y axis is ending with 3.0

But I want both axes to end with same number. For ex. if the max. value in lists (dismax, normax) is 3, then I want to see "3" for both axes. In other words, my diagram should be square.

Answer (score 0):

First,  `lm` is looking for vectors,  not lists so start with

```
dismax<-c(1.14, 2.281, 2.825, 2.965) 
normax<-c(1.8, 2, 2.4, 2.6)
```

To get the axis labels you want try `asp=1`

```
plot(normax, dismax, main="Minute Max.", asp=1,
       xlab="Historical Values ", ylab="Disaggregated Values", pch=19)
abline(lm(normax~dismax), col="red")
```

[image: Plot with regression line]

Comment: This worked, but when I tried with another data, axis labels are getting different. For ex. dismax<-c(0.435, 0.854, 1.214, 2.298) normax<-c(1.7, 3.3, 3.3, 5.2) with these data.